# Undefined method error for a class when used with class variables

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am testing an application using  ruby and watir . I have a file init.rb with this code

```
 class Init_Test
   def initialize
     @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
   end 

   def login_with_creds username,password
     @browser.goto 'https://54.69.254.137/webui#/landing'
     sleep(2)
     @browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
     @browser.button(:class => 'sign-in md-button md-default-
     theme').when_present.click
     sleep(2)
     @browser.text_field(:id =>'input_001').set(username)
     sleep(2)
     @browser.text_field(:id =>'input_002').set(password)
     sleep(2)
     @browser.button(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-theme').click
     sleep(2)
     return @browser
   end
 end
```

I inherit this file into a file called ann.rb

```
require "watir"
require "watir-webdriver"
require_relative 'init'
class Post < Init_Test
  @@b = login_with_creds("abcadmin@example.com","password")

  def test_discuss
    @@b.input(:id =>'input_002').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(aria_label:'What do you want to do?').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(:id =>'select_option_00G').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(aria_label:'About what?').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(:id =>'select_option_00P').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.textarea(:id =>'input_00N').when_present.set('Discuss about java script and later test the    application??')
    sleep(1)
    @@b.span(:text, 'Submit').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
  end

  def test_question
    @@b.input(:id =>'input_002').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(aria_label:'What do you want to do?').when_present.click
    sleep(2)
    @@b.element(:id =>'select_option_014').when_present.click
    sleep(2)
    @@b.element(:id =>'select_017').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.element(:id =>'select_option_01D').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    @@b.textarea(:class =>'ng-pristine md-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-
    required ng-touched').when_present.set('test question')
    sleep(1)
    @@b.span(:text, 'Submit').when_present.click
  end
end

a = Post.new
a.test_discuss
a.test_question
```

As you see I used a class variable `@@b` and assigned the method `log_in_creds` to it and then used the class variable to perform other activities. However when I run it, it throws no method error for `log_In_creds`

```
a.rb:6:in `<class:Post>': undefined method `login_with_creds' for 
Post:Class (NoMethodError)
from a.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

why does it throws error for the class variable. I need to call each method using browser object as I want to initialize the browser only once and perform the required operations later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you call a Ruby method (`methodA`) without explicit receiver, it's the same as calling `self.methodA`. Depending on the position of the code, the object `self` refers to may change.

```
class Init_Test
  # self refers to Init_Test, a class object
  def login_with_creds username,password # define a method for the instances of Init_Test
    # self refers to an instance of Init_Test
  end
end
```

Now, in `Post`:

```
class Post < Init_Test
  @@b = login_with_creds("abcadmin@example.com","password")
```

It will try to call `login_with_creds` with `self` referring to the `Post`, which is a class (singleton) object. However, `login_with_creds` is defined as instance method for all the instances of `Init_Test`, which may be called on all instance of the `Post` class because of the inheritance. It's not for the `Post` object or `Init_Test` object.

Besides, using class variable in test to share data may be error prone. The state of one test may affect the result of another test, which makes the tests not isolated.

You may rewrite it as

```
class Post < Init_Test
  def initialize
    super
    @b = login_with_creds("abcadmin@example.com","password")
  end

  def test_discuss
    @b.input(:id =>'input_002').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    ...
  end

  def test_question
    @b.input(:id =>'input_002').when_present.click
    sleep(1)
    ...
  end
end

a = Post.new
a.test_discuss
a = Post.new # ensure clean state
a.test_question
```

It may be better to use existing test framework such as [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest), [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec), etc.

Comment: Hi I tried re writing it like the way you said, however it throws  the following error:  undefined method `login_with_creds' for   nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)from post_announcements.rb:46:in `new'
from post_announcements.rb:46:in `<main>'

Comment: @MaheshMesta I've updated my code to call super constructor first in `Post`. It may be more clear if you can paste your updated code to the question.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry your code works perfectly.I had forgotten to add 'super' into the code.Thank you so much !!

Comment: @MaheshMesta if it helps, please kindly accept the answer :)